# IE11, VBScript: ActiveX component can't create object: 'outlook.application'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, office365, activex

I'm having a scenario where a (very old) intranet is having issues opening office from within Internet Explorer using VBScript.
The scenario:

1. User clicks on hyperlink
2. is redirected to the following asp page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript>
                Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set myItem = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("<%=template%>")
                myItem.Display
                myItem.To = "<%=EmailTo%>"
                myItem.Display
                window.close()
        </SCRIPT>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#1d4392" >
    </body>
</html>
```

3. Outlook boots, loads the template from disk
4. the end user makes edits and sends the e-mail

Unfortunately, the end users are greeted with the following error:
`VBScript: ActiveX component can't create object: 'outlook.application'`

Some info:

- IE11
- Office 365 64bit
- Win 10 laptops
- The page stopped working since the users migrated to laptops instead of using an RDS-based environment
- The page runs flawlessly on my local machine (which isn't domain joined, as I'm a consultant, also Win10, O365)
- In Event Viewer, I can see Outlook booting up, So I'm quite sure this isn't an IE Security config issue, the page runs under local intranet mode, where VBScript is explisitly allowed through GPO
- I tested Word as well, same issue

Things I tried:

- reinstalling office
- repairing office

Comment: Is IE11 running in 32 or 64 bit? Are the users IE 11 instances running in protected mode?

Answer (score 0):

The "can't create object" is, in most of the case, caused by either :

- the component not being installed
- the component not being registered in the Registry (or is registered in 32 bit but not in 64 bit registry, or conversely)
- a permission problem. Make sure that the Windows user account that is used to run you IIS App Pool have **read + execute** permissions over the folder containing the component DLL, and its dependant DLL's. You can troubleshoot the execution chain by using Process Monitor : https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson4/

Can be downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon